# Do I need a regulator with a standard 5V wall adapter?

Tags: power-supply, pic

I'm about to start my second PIC based project using a PIC16F688, and I have an old cell phone charger (Pantech 5V output). Should I use a regulator (or verify if the adapter is regulated)?

NOTE:
I'm not sure what scenarios warrant the use of a regulator, and which scenarios do not. I'm using the microcontroller to interface with an LCD - so I'm also not sure how sensitive I should expect it to be to 'dirty' power.

Comment: Put a decent sized electrolytic across it and measure the voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measure the no-load voltage with a meter and then measure it with full load. If the two voltages are both about 5V +/- 0.5 volts you may get away without a regulator (and that's if you need a 5V supply to your PIC). You might also need to add extra decoupling capacitors to avoid too much ripple or switching noise from the internal regulator it may use.